# NSS pin goes high immediately

Tags: c, spi, stm32f0

I'm working on a simple project with stm32f0. the project is when I push the button on the board, the SPI1 of the MCU should send the data. all things work nicely but there is a problem. look at the EXTI interrupt routine:

```
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_4 , GPIO_PIN_RESET );
  HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT( &hspi1 , (uint8_t*)aTxBuffer , 9 );
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_4 , GPIO_PIN_SET );
}
```

two functions handle the EXTI interrupt then ignore them. third function is this `HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_4 , GPIO_PIN_RESET );` that it reset the GPIOA4 pin. after this, we have to send the data. ok then we use this function `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT( &hspi1 , (uint8_t*)aTxBuffer , 9 );` and for end up we have to set the pin again. then I use this function `HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_4 , GPIO_PIN_SET );`. alright, now lets to see the result.

[image: figure1]

oh! can you see? the NSS pin goes high immediately! Why?

the `HAL_GPIO_WritePin` function:

```
/**
  * @brief  Sets or clears the selected data port bit.
  * 
  * @note   This function uses GPIOx_BSRR register to allow atomic read/modify 
  *         accesses. In this way, there is no risk of an IRQ occurring between
  *         the read and the modify access.
  *               
  * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A..F) to select the GPIO peripheral for STM32F0 family
  * @note   GPIOE is available only for STM32F072.
  * @note   GPIOD is not available for STM32F031.  
  *         For STM32F051 and STM32F030: (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, (2) for GPIOD and (0..1, 4..7) for GPIOF.
  *         For STM32F072: (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD, GPIOE, (0..10) for GPIOF.
  *         For STM32F031: (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, (13..15) for GPIOC and (0..1, 6..7) for GPIOF.  
  * @param  GPIO_Pin: specifies the port bit to be written.
  *          This parameter can be one of GPIO_PIN_x where x can be (0..15).
  * @param  PinState: specifies the value to be written to the selected bit.
  *          This parameter can be one of the GPIO_PinState enum values:
  *            @arg GPIO_BIT_RESET: to clear the port pin
  *            @arg GPIO_BIT_SET: to set the port pin
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, GPIO_PinState PinState)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));
  assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN_ACTION(PinState));

  if (PinState != GPIO_PIN_RESET)
  {
    GPIOx->BSRRL = GPIO_Pin;
  }
  else
  {
    GPIOx->BSRRH = GPIO_Pin ;
  }
}
```

the `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT` function:

```
/**
  * @brief  Transmit an amount of data in no-blocking mode with Interrupt
  * @param  hspi: SPI handle
  * @param  pData: pointer to data buffer
  * @param  Size: amount of data to be sent
  * @retval HAL status
  */
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)
{
  assert_param(IS_SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_OR_1LINE(hspi->Init.Direction));

  if(hspi->State == HAL_SPI_STATE_READY)
  {
    if((pData == NULL) || (Size == 0)) 
    {
      return  HAL_ERROR;                                    
    }

    /* Process Locked */
    __HAL_LOCK(hspi);

    hspi->State       = HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY_TX;
    hspi->ErrorCode   = HAL_SPI_ERROR_NONE;
    hspi->pTxBuffPtr  = pData;
    hspi->TxXferSize  = Size;
    hspi->TxXferCount = Size;
    hspi->pRxBuffPtr  = NULL;
    hspi->RxXferSize  = 0;
    hspi->RxXferCount = 0;

    /* Set the function for IT treatement */
    if(hspi->Init.DataSize > SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT )
    {
      hspi->RxISR = NULL;
      hspi->TxISR = SPI_TxISR_16BIT;
    }
    else
    {
      hspi->RxISR = NULL;
      hspi->TxISR = SPI_TxISR_8BIT;
    }

    /* Configure communication direction : 1Line */
    if(hspi->Init.Direction == SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE)
    {
      __HAL_SPI_1LINE_TX(hspi);
    }

    /* Reset CRC Calculation */
    if(hspi->Init.CRCCalculation == SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLED)
    {
      __HAL_SPI_RESET_CRC(hspi);    
    }

    /* Enable TXE and ERR interrupt */
    __HAL_SPI_ENABLE_IT(hspi,(SPI_IT_TXE));

    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hspi);

    /* Note : The SPI must be enabled after unlocking current process 
              to avoid the risk of SPI interrupt handle execution before current
              process unlock */

    /* Check if the SPI is already enabled */ 
    if((hspi->Instance->CR1 &SPI_CR1_SPE) != SPI_CR1_SPE)
    {
      /* Enable SPI peripheral */    
      __HAL_SPI_ENABLE(hspi);
    }

    return HAL_OK;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}
```

this is the configuration for GPIOA4:

```
/*Configure GPIO pin : PA4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Comment: It would seem that since your HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT() routine is non-blocking, you will need to test for it's completion before executing HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_4 , GPIO_PIN_SET );

Comment: ... Perhaps the place to do this would be at the end of the hspi Tx Interrupt Service Routine.

Comment: @Tut I think the second your comment is the point! ok, let to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT does not actually send any data. It merely invokes __HAL_SPI_ENABLE which executes after the ISR is done.

Comment: Then How can I know that it has been sent the data?

Comment: Perhaps by TXE interrupt. When you get there, wait until BSY is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Since your HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT() routine is non-blocking, you will need to test for it's completion before executing HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_4 , GPIO_PIN_SET );

The place to do this would most likely be at the end of the hspi Tx Interrupt Service Routine.